# UIKeyboard is not visible after reload a view

Tags: uitextfield, uiinterfaceorientation, uikeyboard

We've a UIViewController for login on our application, the first load works perfectly, but after a logout, when we back to the login page, we detect some unexpected problem for 6.1 version.

I configure the events keyboardDidShow and keyboardWillHide based on notifications, because the Keyboard appear out of the screen.

If I print the CGRect of the keyboard based on the UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey, the behavior is very estrange:

First field:  {{inf, inf}, {0, 0}}
Second field: {{160, 487}, {0, 0}}

Additionally the interfaceOrientation is always unknown when the problem appears.

[image: Keyboard location after]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

On the didFinishLoad / AppDelegate we had this code:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window addSubview:self.viewController.view];
```

I replace it (removing the first line):

```
// Add to the windows the iForceViewController view
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

Is a crappy solution, because we include the first line in order to solve unexpected behavior on rotations.

Thanks